# Getting an element using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, winforms, html-agility-pack

I want to get a div from my html document that has no id or name, but has a unique style tag.

Here is what I tried:

```
        foreach (HtmlNode node in myDocument.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes())
        {
            if (node.OuterHtml.Contains("div"))
            {
                HtmlAttribute att = node.Attributes["style"];

                if (att != null)
                {

                    if (att.ToString() == "font-size:16px;padding:4px 8px 0")
                    {
                        targetDiv = node;
                    }
                }
            }
           }
```

First I got all of the nodes in document, then I tried to filter out only the divs using:

```
if (node.OuterHtml.Contains("div"))
```

However, this isn't actually filtering out the divs but selecting any tag which has `div` in it. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try XPath:

```
var nodes = myDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@style='font-size:16px;padding:4px 8px 0']")
```

Comment: I used `myDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")` but this works too.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than

```
if (node.OuterHtml.Contains("div"))
```

Try using teh `Name` property:

```
if (node.Name == "div")
```

I'm not familiar with HtmlAgilityPack, however after a little reading around, you might find [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx) helpful.

Comment: Yes, I tought `Name` actually meant the name attribute and not the tag. I used `myDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")` in the end and it worked.